# Compare each element in one array which contains all Elements from another Array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have 2 array like below :

Array 1 :

3.3.3.3

2.2.2.2

1.1.1.1

3.3.3.3

1.1.1.5

1.1.1.3

1.1.1.4

1.1.1.3,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2

2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1,1.1.1.3

Array 2:

1.1.1.3

2.2.2.2

1.1.1.1

As you can see Array1[6] and Array1[7] contains all the values from Array 2 .

My code in Powershell:

```
$siIPs = $sourceIPsource.IpAddress 
if ($siIPs.Count -gt 1) 
{ 
  $siIPs= $siIPs -join ',' 
} 
if($initialuniversalipsets.value -contains $siIPs) 
{ 
  $index=$initialuniversalipsets.value.IndexOf($siIPs) Write-host $index 
} 

Below are array value:
H:\Modules> $initialuniversalipsets.value 3.3.3.3 2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1 3.3.3.3 1.1.1.5 1.1.1.3 1.1.1.4 1.1.1.3,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2 1.1.1.3,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2 
H:\Modules> $tg 1.1.1.3 2.2.2.2 1.1.1.1
```

How can I get the first element in first array contains all the values from second array ordered?

Comment: The expectation is that you attempt to code solution yourself and post that code, and SO users help you work out any issues. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Are you wanting the line number or array index of the array1 element that contains all elements from array2 as a comma-delimited string?

Comment: @AdminOfThings : thanks for your reply . will try to put code next time .Yes , i want array index that contains all elements from array2 as a comma-delimited string  .  I tried to join array 2 by ',   like this  $array2= $array2 -join ','  and then compared with array 1 .  But i then realized  that  elements in array 2 can be in any order in array1   so   i was able to get Array1[6] but not array[7] which contains all the elements from array2 but in diffrent order.

Comment: sorry making my self clear , I wagely understood  when you said    "comma-delimited string"   i  want to compare  whole array 2 with  each element in array . since  each value in array 1 is separated by ,  Just like a IP address array

Comment: @TarunGupta - you need to post your code THIS TIME, not "net time". [*grin*] please, do so ...

Comment: $siIPs =$sourceIPsource.IpAddress
 if ($siIPs.Count -gt 1)
 {
 $siIPs= $siIPs -join ','
 }

 if($initialuniversalipsets.value -contains $siIPs)
  {
   $index=$initialuniversalipsets.value.IndexOf($siIPs)
   Write-host $index
   }
   Below are array value :H:\Modules> $initialuniversalipsets.value
3.3.3.3
2.2.2.2,1.1.1.1
3.3.3.3
1.1.1.5
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.3,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2
1.1.1.3,1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2

 H:\Modules> $tg
1.1.1.3
2.2.2.2
1.1.1.1

Comment: @Lee_Dailey:  my script is like 1500 lines .  Array 1 and array 2 which i originally asked are repesenting " $initialuniversalipsets.value " and $siIPs respectively .  is this clear ?

Comment: @TarunGupta - [1] _please_, put your info in the Question where others can find it ... and wrap it in code formatting to make it easy to read. [2] this site is for help with code. you are _expected_ to post a **_minimal example of the problem that others can test_**. that includes both just enuf code to show the problem you have AND the needed sample data to work with that code. >>> How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example <<<